# What algorithms and tools should I be using to create a CSS specificity calculator?

Tags: c++, css, algorithm, css-specificity

I'm thinking about making a function that calculates [CSS specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/), which is a fairly simple calculation. Basically, every instance of `#somestring` is worth `100`, every instance of `.somestring` or `:somestring` is worth `10` and every instance of `somestring` is worth `1`.

**Examples:**

`"#mydiv p"` ---> `101`

`"ul>li>a"` ---> `3`

`"div.pull-right img"` --> `12`

`"body#homepage #home-side-box div.row.pull-left[name="thisrow"]:after"` --> `232`

So the function would be something like

```
unsigned long specificity ( const std::string & slctr )
{
    // ....
}
```

Now, I'm not expecting this to be a simple implementation, for I realize there is a number of nuances that will go into it, but I'm wondering if someone can give me some hints about algorithms and tools I should be using to make something efficient and clean. For instance, I'm assuming I should be using `std::regex_iterator` -- is that right?

Comment: Actually the values are `0,1,0,0`, `0,0,1,0` and `0,0,0,1`. They shouldn't be treated as decimal numbers. For instance, an ID selector is more specific than thousands of class selectors.

Comment: As Hashem says: 1, 10 and 100 are "layman's terms". A better definition is "some extremely large number N to the powers 0, 1, 2, 3".

Comment: What ARE the exact numbers then?

Comment: @DepakChopra: There are no exact numbers, that is on purpose. It's defined like that so e.g. no matter how many tag names you use in the selector, a single class is always enough to have higher specificity. Hence "N".

Answer (score 1):

The specificity of a selector is not really a number. You can't compare the different types of specificity to one another as if they are integers.

In your example, where you assign 10 to a class and 1 to a tag name, it would mean that if a selector contains more than 10 tag names, it would have a greater specificity than one with only a class. But that is not how it works.

What you could do, if you absolutely insist on returning a single value, is use very large differences, say, 2<sup>12</sup> for a class and 2<sup>24</sup> for an ID. Then the algorithm would only fail on selectors with more than 4096 tag names.

The proper approach, however, is not to try to calculate a single value, but to make a function that compares two selectors. If one selector contains more IDs than the other, its specificity is highest; return "one". If the number of IDs is the same, then compare the number of classes. And so on, until you find a difference, or else you return "equal".